# background gradient in ionic app

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I have the following app:

```
<ion-content class="padding sign-in-form">
    <div > My APP</div>
      <div class="list list-inset" style="padding: 15px">
        <label class="item item-input">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Username" ng-model="data.username">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
          <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="data.password">
        </label>
        <button class="button button-block button-energized" ng-click="login()">Login</button>
        <button class="button button-small button-outline button-assertive" ng-click="signup()">SIGN UP</button>
        <button class="button button-clear button-stable" style="float: right;">
          Forgot Password
        </button>

      </div>
    </ion-content>

<style>
  .sign-in-form{
    background: linear-gradient(#FF9C1B, #FFC837);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #FF9C1B , #FFC837); /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to left,#FF9C1B , #FFC837); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
  }
</style>
```

When i preview the app in ionic view on a ios device, i see the background gradient, but when i start the same thing on a android device, there is no background color/gradient. I am using ionic view app to preview apps.

Comment: Same problem here. Struggling with it for hours. Did you find a way to fix it or any workaround? Thanks

Comment: well instead of doing it on ion-content, I played around a bit by putting this gradient in a wrapper div and things like that. It somehow worked on latest android devices. I am not sure if it worked on my galaxy s3 (I tested initially on s3 but then it met with an accident, and all subsequent tests were on nexus :P). The best way is to play around by putting this gradient class at different levels in the hierarchy and see where it works :P